# Encrypting with DES with user input password

Tags: c#, encryption, des

I'm still studying cryptography. I'm trying to create a simple static function in C# that encrypts string to DES (with a Base64 ouput). I learned that DES use 8-Byte as its key. I want the user to input string of any length, use it as the key to encrypt the message, then convert it to Base64. Example is in this [site](https://www.tools4noobs.com/online_tools/encrypt/).

```
public static string EncryptDES(string phrase, string key)
{
    string encrypted = "";

    byte[] phraseBytes = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(phrase);
    byte[] keyBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);

    System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashMD5Provider 
                                = new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    System.Security.Cryptography.DESCryptoServiceProvider provider 
                                = new System.Security.Cryptography.DESCryptoServiceProvider();

    provider.Mode = System.Security.Cryptography.CipherMode.CBC;

    System.Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform transform 
                                = provider.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, keyBytes);
    System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode mode 
                                = System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Write;



    System.IO.MemoryStream memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream cryptoStream 
                                = new System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream(memStream, transform, mode);
    cryptoStream.Write(phraseBytes, 0, phraseBytes.Length);
    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

    byte[] encryptedMessageBytes = new byte[memStream.Length];
    memStream.Position = 0;
    memStream.Read(encryptedMessageBytes, 0, encryptedMessageBytes.Length);

    encrypted = System.Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedMessageBytes);

    return (encrypted);
} // private static string EncryptDES(string phrase, string key) { }
```

Then call it like this in Main:

```
SimpleEncryption.EncryptDES("A message regarding some secure 512-bit  encryption", "AnUltimatelyVeryVeryLongPassword");
```

When a user inputs a random number of string length (whether greater than or less than 8 characters), a cryptographic exception always happens in this line:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform transform = provider.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, keyBytes);
```

It says `Specified key is not a valid size for this algorithm.`

Removing parts of the key to fit in the length of 8 characters (with or without hashing) doesn't seems to be a secure solution (there might be a high rate of collision).

How can I implement DES (not 3DES) with a user input string?

Comment: have you take a look at `LegalKeySizes` property? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.legalkeysizes(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes. I understand DES uses 64-bit long key but how can we fit the user input password to match the key used to encrypt a string?

Comment: DESCryptoServiceProvider des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
            Console.WriteLine("DESCryptoServiceProvider ");
            ks = des.LegalKeySizes;
            foreach (KeySizes k in ks)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\tLegal min key size = " + k.MinSize);
                Console.WriteLine("\tLegal max key size = " + k.MaxSize);
            }

Comment: In fact, I use a library from CodeProject website.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate a hash from the user's password and take only 8 bytes to use as your key.

```
var fullHash = hashMD5Provider.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key));
var keyBytes = new byte[8];
Array.Copy(fullHash , keyBytes, 8);
```

Your question expressed concern about hash collisions from throwing away part of the hash; yes, that certainly does increase the risk, but (assuming your hash algorithm is good) you're no worse off than if you just used a hash algorithm that only produced 8 bytes to begin with.  A good hash algorithm should distribute the entropy evenly.

Comment: MD5 is a very weak key derivation function and is not suitable for production use. Instead iIterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `PBKDF2`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force. Protecting your users is important, please use secure password methods.

Comment: @zaph The OP was already using the MD5 hash algorithm in his posted code.  I was merely trying to show the minimal amount of code to get it working, not endorsing his choice of hash algorithm.

Comment: Like helping some jump off a bridge? Oh wait, that is not a good idea either. Here is the thing, it not about the OP's code, it is about putting the users of the application at risk.

Comment: @zaph Your comment would be more relevant if the OP was actually saving the hash somewhere.  He's not.  There's nothing to brute-force except the encrypted DES stream.

Comment: PBKDF2 (Password Based Key Derivation Function 2) is indeed for deriving encryption keys from passwords, exactly what the OP is doing. In order to brute force the encryption it is not the key but the password that is attacked. Decryption is fast, especially if only a small amount needs to be decrypted in order to determine if the key is correct. That is why a slow function is needed to derive the key from the password, MD5 is fast, PBKDF2 is generally used with an iteration count such that it requires around 100ms.

Comment: IMO it helps to point out what is secure, what isn't and to promote secure solutions. It is the users that loose with poor security.